# Run method only after other

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocos2d-iphone, callback, block

i need to make this methods:
1) find and remove matches
2) fill empty cells 
3) do 1 and 2 while no matches found
4) only when no matches found - find reshuffle method

How i do this :

```
        [self launchAsyncCheckAndFill:^{
            [self isReshuffleNeeded];
        }];

-(void)launchAsyncCheckAndFill:(void(^)(void))completionHandler {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(check) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:true];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler();
        });
    });
}

- (void) check {

    [self performSelector:@selector(fillEmptyCells) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        if ([self checkMapForMatchesWithFindMatchesMode:NO isCopyVector:NO]) {
            [self check];
        }
    });
}
```

First of all i'm remove matches, then i go this methods : first of all i go launchAsyncCheckAndFill method, that on call back must start reshuffle method.
launchAsyncCheckAndFill must send callback only when check method is done. Check method is done in loop, this method must always fillEmptyCells, then checkmatches and while matches not found, only then must work callback on launchAsyncCheckAndFill .

But now behavior, that in loop always removing match, but method on reshuffle works after first remove and fill.
btw time 0.4 , 0.5 it's for animation, for this time figures moves and changes position. unfortunately in cocos i can only use

```
[elem.sprite runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0.4f position:elemPos1]];
```

that put position only after delay.

UPDATE:

```
[self launchAsyncCheckAndFills];
[self isReshuffleNeeded];

-(void)launchAsyncCheckAndFills {

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        [self check];
    });


dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_release(group);
}

- (void) check {

    [self performSelector:@selector(fillEmptyCells) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        if ([self checkMapForMatchesWithFindMatchesMode:NO isCopyVector:NO]) {
            [self check];
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to answer this before you explain why you're using GCD. It seems you're trying to multi-thread something just because you can, which is why you're in trouble in the first place. The message to performSelectorOnMainThread within a dispatch_async that does nothing else speaks for itself. You could probably just as well run performSelectorInBackground for the work you need done in the background, or a single dispatch_async with a dispatch_group_wait at the appropriate time if you need to wait for some work to be done.

Comment: Thanks for a comment, answer is simple: it's only one way that i found how i can to run operation only after other worked to the end include delay. 
But if i will use performSelectorInBackground, then how i will block thread untill method not worked to the end ? Please show me example,i'm too pure with this task, i will very appreciate this!

Comment: Maybe take an hour to read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091  You can just use dispatch_sync to queue multiple blocks that run in order. If you need to run multiple blocks concurrently, create a dispatch group and then use dispatch_group_wait to wait until all blocks of the group are complete. It seems you're making this more complicated because you haven't taken the time to learn GCD, but reading the docs is time well invested. ;)

Comment: Please look updated version, the big trouble, that when i use delay, it doesn't go inside loop, so in this variant it always wait and nothing happened, but if i change methods with delay on [self fillEmptyCells] for example, it will be good,but without delay, that i need